# Does getUniqueID() from react-native-device-info can ever change?

Tags: react-native, react-native-device-info

I have a few questions:

1.Does getUniqueID() from react-native-device-info library can ever change? Or it’s staying the same all the time

2. If it can change what parameter that his unique for the device from react-native-device-info library can’t be never change?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It will change on ios if the user deletes the app. But not in android prior to oreo. Here's the link about the IDFV https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor. This picture is from the react-native-device-info readme.

So if you have only one app in the app store and the user deletes your app, the unique ID won't stay the same. But if the user has more than just app from you, the id will be the same cause this will come from the app still on the device.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What about update the app the key still stay the same?

Comment: Yes he should stay the same

Comment: I got a different device id. production and environment mode both are diff